# Axioms in science and the scientific method

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics

Do axioms exist in the scientific method like in physics, chemistry, biology, …? E.g. Ockham's Razor for picking the best theory – is it an axiom? Another example is that science gathers data, analyzes it and comes to a conclusion through reasoning (usually through inductive reasoning)… but can these axioms change in the future if we find a better way? Or would they be forever set (because they are axioms)?

Comment: No. "Scientific method" is a loose collection of research techniques that vary from discipline to discipline and can not be formalized into "axioms", it is an art or a craft rather than theory. Only some vague general principles are common and they do change over time, sometimes they are called [scientific paradigms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm).

Comment: To build on Conifold's answer:  for example, the consensus position among professional philosophers of biology today is that [biology does not have laws](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=368812428808648779&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) in anything like the way physics is often understood to have laws.  The laws (or a subset of them) would be the axioms in an formal axiomatization of biology.  Since there are no laws of biology, there are no axioms of biology either.

Comment: Conifold & Dan Hicks. Superb comments, if you will accept the praise. There's more wisdom in these comments than in many answers.

Comment: However, I think one may say that e.g. the natural/physical sciences work on the axiom that the material world exists.

Comment: 'Occam's Razor' is not a real thing. It is a crude 'rule of thumb' and nothing more. It can never be used to seriously rigorously defend anything. There is no actual bias toward simplicity in integration with our existing beliefs (which is what the 'razor' relies upon) in reality.

Comment: @cbeleites - I'm not sure you're right here. The metaphysical existence of the physical world is not a necessary axiom for physics but a voluntary philosophical choice. Physics is not concerned with metaphysics so has no need for this axiom and it serves no purpose.

Comment: @PeterJ: I agree accepting or assuming the existence of the physical world is a philosophical choice. For many people I'd also describe it as a religious belief (as in: dogma). I decided to use the term axiom as I want to avoid triggering religious discussions. What I'm looking for is a term that describes in an emotionally neutral way a fundamentally unprovable basic assumption that is needed to start working. The following question is to help me understanding your point: In case the physical world does not exist, what do, say, physics or chemistry or biology study?

Comment: @cbeleites - Probably not much to disgaree about. I was suggesting that the metaphysical existence of the world is not a necessary axiom since it is not needed for physics to begin work. It can study the material world while making no metaphysical commitments and according to its method should do this. I'm not sure what axioms are required for physics and am still pondering but they won't be metaphysical.

Comment: @PeterJ: Can you give me an example how physics can start without the physical world (= the target of its studies) existing? I mean, if this physical world does not exist, how am I to conduct experiments which are the most fundamental way of judging/checking/measuring whether my thoughts and theories are correct? I'm stuck thinking that the non-existence of the physical world would take away (degrade to pure thought experiment) a most important and necessary tool which cannot be replaced (at least not in our current scientific method for studying the physical world).

Comment: @cbeleites - We're talking metaphysics here. By non-existence is meant not that the appearances of things do not appear (obviously) but that what appears has no metaphysical or fundamental existence. You could think of the physicists in the Matrix. They also thought they were studying real phenomena. It makes no difference to physics whether we are in the Matrix or not since it does not study fundamentals. Note that the idea is not that things are non-existent (obviously) but that they are reducible and have no intrinsic existence or existence 'from their own side'.

Comment: @PeterJ: exactly (I'd say: what if solipsists are right and materialists aren't). So yes, I was wrong: We don't need existence of the physical world, we need consistency of reaction of what we study (otherwise the strategy of forecast -> experiment -> check does not work), I think this is a more clear axiom/assumption/necessary condition. Thanks for helping me to clarify my thoughts :-) However, this consistency is an important property we ascribe to the physical world as we *believe* it to be. Going one step further, claiming the natural sciences describe + predict *the* physical world...

Comment: ... relies on the existence of that physical world. And implies that its nature is as we believe it to be. What I'm missing in some natural scientists' claims and many discussions about natural science is acknowledging that from the inside we cannot know whether *the* physical world exists (I didn't think of Matrix-like outside simulations but rather of the solipsist version of a world). And that we (I'm natural scientist as well) pragmatically *believe* (in the religious sense) in it or assume it to be real in order to feel sensible in what we're doing. So: natural science describing the...

Comment: laws of the physical world only needs consistency (if that's missing we have no laws) but claiming the findings to be real needs the (unprovable within the natural sciences) assumption that the physical world exists. But this is nothing very special: all our "facts" degrade to fiction if our "real" world is in fact a simulation (outside or in our own thoughts).

Comment: @cbeleites - We seem to be on roughly the same page. It's not that the psycho-physical world does not exist but that is does not do so in the way that we usually imagine. Thus for instance Nagarjuna's famous proof of Buddhist metaphysics is said to prove not that nothing exists but that 'nothing really exists', where the 'really' is an important proviso. Whether he is right or wrong makes no difference to physics but makes a vast difference to philosophy. On this view solipsism would be neither strictly true or false, which would explain why it is undecidable.

Comment: @Conifold it may not be "formalized" yet but that doesn't mean a formalization can't exist. In order for someone to believe in science they must assume some underlying aspects of reality must be true. These things are the axioms of science and they CAN be formalized. So we do assume logic to be recursively real, and we assume probability is real and applies to events that happen in reality. Neither of the previous two facts can be derived or proven to be true.... we simply assume it is true and therefore they are "axioms."

Comment: @BrianYeh You are confusing ontology with methodology. There may be "axioms" describing reality, and its laws would be the "theorems", but the "scientific method" is not about them (ontology). It is about the process of discovering them by limited beings like us (methodology). Logic and probability play a very small role in that process (related to testing), whatever we assume about them, and "formalizing" the creative side of it is not only pointless but often counterproductive.

Comment: @Conifold Nobody is asking you to formalize anything here. As long as you admit a  formalization is possible, then axioms exist. To use the scientific method you must believe it in it. To believe in something you must assume it to be true. Nobody believes in science just because it's called science. They believe in science because science draws on certain aspects of reality that we assume to be true. Namely the only axioms required to believe in science is to believe logic and probability (both of which have ALREADY been formalized despite your declaration that such an endeavor is useless)

Comment: @BrianYeh What exactly would it formalize? How people come up with scientific theories? That is worse than impossible, it is nonsensical. Can "theory of everything" be formalized? Perhaps. You are talking about formalization of one thing and then infer axioms for something else. And people can believe in science because its methods are better than the alternatives, it can be for pragmatic or some other reasons. They do not have to believe something about reality to do that. Logic and probability are commonly taken to regulate our means of description, not reality itself.

Comment: @Conifold Coming up with a hypothesis would likely in itself be taken as an axiom as creativity is to complicated to formalize. In the same way that mathematics doesn't formalize the "creativity" mathematicians themselves use to formulate proofs you don't don't do the same with science. Testing, observation, quantitative analysis which is the greater majority of what the scientific method describes can be formalized. In fact they already are formalized just not "unified" under science. Statistics, logic and probability taken in aggregate can be thought of as a formalization.

Comment: @Conifold No. You are wrong about logic and probability. These are assumptions we take to be true, and we have no explanation why they are true. Formal probability, for example, is like a logic game, it is just a semantic game we play with formal rules that present numerical outputs we call "probabilities." No one in the human race knows the reason why when we roll a 6 sided dice 1000 times, generally 1/6th of the rolls will be a 4. No one knows why the arbitrary rules of probability apply to reality as we know it and therefore science. The same is said for logic. These are all assumptions.

Comment: @BrianYeh Or, they are bookkeeping devices of our representation system and it makes no sense to call them true or false. They can only be useful or not, for  certain tasks. Fair die is just an idealization that fits some real dice and not others. In other fields, like biology, simplistic idealizations are much less useful and one has to get more creative. And you need to generate hypotheses before logic and probability are of use, their axioms won't help you with that. But evolving and field specific heuristics will, and *they* are the core of scientific methodology.

Comment: @Conifold All language and names are book keeping devices for aspects of reality that are real. That fact is a pointless tangent. The concept underlying the book keeping device is what is assumed to be true. We assume if a perfect fair die existed in reality the rules of probability would apply and that is the reason why the rules still generally apply for real world imperfect die. This is 100% true. Go read up on the literature on this. Probability is a fundamental assumption of reality as stated by the literature.

Comment: @Conifold The core of mathematics is creatively coming up with axioms and proofs. Yet despite the creativity; all of math is formalized ANYWAY. It's the same thing with science. You can formalize a good portion of what science actually is without touching creativity. Understanding of this will help you understand the true nature of science instead of the vague populist notion of science that your regurgitating to me right now.

Comment: @BrianYeh We do not need to assume anything about a perfect fair die, it is our own tool, it behaves as we prescribe. Nor do we need to assume that its approximations occur in reality. If they do, well and good, if not, we'll employ something else. Speaking of literature, here is Yablo:"*It is no big surprise if things with representing as their reason for “being” show a consistent aptitude for the task.*" And you are still confused, coming up with new conceptions and proofs is as heuristic and unformalizable in mathematics as it is in science. What *is* formalized is not methodology.

Comment: @Conifold No. A perfect fair dice in reality obeys the laws of reality, it does not obey you.You are highly confused. No real dice obeys your commands, only imaginary die can obey your commands. If you choose to describe your imaginary die with probability so be it, nobody is talking about imaginary die here. We are talking about a real die that exist in reality. The literature is here: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/probability.html#4 a statistics textbook. Statistics applies probability to the real world and thus what it states as axioms are relevant.

Comment: @BrianYeh Perfection is imaginary, not real, your textbook simply *defines* "fair die" as obeying equidistribution. And if reality does not obey our imaginary models we replace them. Even logic and probability, should the need arise. That's science, no need to "assume" and "formalize" anything in advance. Your projection of models onto reality is called platonism, charming but naive. And even accepting it, we gain little on methodology. Probability axioms are relevant to interpreting those aspects of reality that models incorporating them approximate, not to methods of building the models.

Comment: Logic and probability are fundamental parts of the scientific method. If they are not true the scientific method is not true. For science we assume these to be true. There is no replacement. The foundation breaks down once these are determined not to be true. SIgh. When will you understand? You just don't get it. You're going off on tangents. Probability is the thing we use to determine whether models have validity. Once you remove probability it's all over. Get it?

Comment: @BrianYeh Of course, scientific method is not "true". No method is true or false, it can only be fit for a task, or not. Even when the adjective is applied metaphorically to tools, as in "tried and true", that is what it means. And there are plenty of replacements for [foundationalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justep-foundational/) in the literature, so nothing breaks down without a foundation. Methods need not be "assumed" once and for all, they are updated in the course of practice. You can still believe in foundationalism, but the idea that science requires it is factually false.

Comment: @conifold then why do you use the method and why do you trust it if it's not true? The truthiness of anything doesn't matter that's just pedantic stupidity we don't need to go there. What matters is you live your entire life using technology derived from science. You live your life assuming science is true. Don't use foundationalism as a defense, it's just more pedantic illusions that deride from the main point. Let me put it in a way you understand: probability and logic IS science. They are one and the same. More specifically Science is a consequence of probability and logic.

Comment: @BrianYeh Because it worked before in similar situations. When you try to fix a car do you *assume* that it will work? You try what tools you have and adjust them as you go along. You trust them enough to use, but do not assume they are always sufficient or adequate. And you do not need to, they are open to improvement. Science is a lot more than logic and probability, it gives guidance on what to do while they can give none, only help judge what is already done. And that is why they can be formalized and scientific method cannot be.

Comment: @Conifold. Other than probability and logic itself nobody assumes anything to a 100% degree. I don't assume it will work, I assume it MIGHT work. Keyword: MIGHT. If something MIGHT work it means that it's probable that it can work. Hence if I assume that it MIGHT work I am assuming PROBABILITY is true. The guidance and the utility of science is not science itself. We use MATH to help us do engineering and architecture, doesn't mean engineering is math. The scientific method at it's core is: hypothesis, experiment and analysis. The results of the "analysis" can be used for other fields.

Comment: @BrianYeh If something might work then probability is true??? Those people who tried things before probability theory, mighty of them to "assume" stuff they had no clue about. And if science's guidance is not science itself how is scientific method supposed to guide making hypotheses, conducting experiments and analyzing results? It is not like inverse square law, Foucault pendulum or Faraday's lines of force came out of axioms of logic and probability.

Comment: @Conifold Mathematical models like Faraday's lines of force are verified against observations statistically. Statistics itself is not verified at all, thus it is an axiom. Hence probability is a axiom that humans assume is true about the universe. Additionally these laws aren't derived from probability. They are "verified" by applying probability. The only macro physical phenomenon that is "derived" from probability is entropy. You will note there are no statistical verification's on entropy because it is in itself a probabilistic phenomenon. Probability and by extension entropy is an axiom.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, axioms do exist. Underlying the processes of science are several philosophical assumptions--aka 'axioms' or 'first principles.' They are necessary for making any and all inferences from scientific data, and really, even for the application and method of science itself. We take them for granted--like most philosophy--and don't think about them much. They are unspoken but very present and real.  They are a baseline we cannot go beyond which means they provide the foundation for all empirical science while being empirically unprovable themselves.

The principle of contradiction, of the excluded middle, of noncontradiction, of identity, of intelligibility, of sufficient reason, of causal closure, of finality, and at least one principle of substance, are all ‘first principles’ that have been demonstrated through application *after* being used, but which cannot, themselves, be anything but assumed *a priori*.

We must assume the universe is a basically rational place; that cause and effect are rationally predictable at least with probability; and that knowledge from the past provides a rational foundation for studying the present and predicting the future. In other words, we must assume the laws of causality and the uniformity of nature for science and also for knowledge itself.

Hume wrote on the uniformity of nature demonstrating its unreliability and its unavoidable nature as an assumption at the same time, but without it, most of the past would be undecipherable to us.

Insofar as anyone can tell, our universe is orderly and logical.  This is an inference made using reductionism, which assumes that studying a part of something will produce real knowledge of the whole.  Reductionism represents a certain perspective on causality, and while it is not a universally supported assumption, (since some claim reductionism produces a fragmented picture of reality, when reality is actually composed of wholes), it is a necessary assumption for most of the day-to-day work of science. Astrophysicists remain open to finding alternative answers about the universe itself, of course, but reductionism remains one of the three most basic--and useful--foundational assumptions of all science.

All of this assumes reason, and experience, are dependable sources of knowledge. People are likely to breeze across this one with a snort and “of course they are!” However, what most assume is the dependability of their own experiences; they do not assume the dependability of someone else’s. Hence the response, “I don’t care what your experience is, it doesn’t line up with mine, therefore you are clearly deluded.” Some experiences can be misleading, yet there we are-—we have to assume reason and experience are dependable ways to knowing or we have no way to know anything at all.

We must assume our minds are capable of understanding nature.  'Truths' may be out there, but if we can’t discern them, how can we know?  Science must assume it is possible to know, to discover—-not to create-—but to find, real knowledge and understanding or there would be no science at all.

There can be no knowledge without a 'knowing agent', therefore this assumes the existence of a “mind” and a “self” that is capable of interacting with a real world around it. This has become an increasingly argued assumption due to Nick Bostrom's simulation hypothesis trilemma--which serves to demonstrate that it has been an assumption.

Science consists of taking measurements or conducting experiments, and the data from those help scientists develop new hypotheses and theories. This assumes  error is correctable with new data, and that knowledge is attainable; without that science stops. This assumes some kind of ‘truth’ is a real thing — that truth can be found and error shown and identified and corrected. This assumes that not all knowledge is equal.

This is an extensive but not an exhaustive list.

Yes axioms exist in science.  They are the foundation of all empirical reasoning, but, as they are not founded on empiricism, they are not falsifiable, so they generally don't change much. But they can be challenged.  There are a few that are currently undergoing significant challenges.  Causal closure--the assumption that everything physical has a physical cause--for example, is currently undergoing a significant challenge from philosophy of mind advocates.  Reductionism has been and continues to face challenges.  The very nature of our reality and perception are being challenged by Bostrom and his supporters.

There are always challenges, but axioms remain in one form or another.

http://aynrandlexicon.com/lexicon/causality.html
http://www.nyu.edu/gsas/dept/philo/courses/modern05/Hume_on_empirical_reasoning.pdf
https://books.google.com/books?id=WuD8yaYxv-wC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Self-Knowing+Agents,+by+Lucy+O%E2%80%99Brien.&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7scLd6pfnAhXSmeAKHf9lAuYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=Self-Knowing%20Agents%2C%20by%20Lucy%20O%E2%80%99Brien.&f=false
https://www.iep.utm.edu/red-ism/
https://academic.oup.com/pq/article-abstract/65/261/626/1506037?redirectedFrom=fulltext
https://www.jstor.org/stable/3751725?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3Aed50644791272fdb31afc0204f3cde52&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Most of your explanation states an obvious but important axiom. It can be summed up as: We assume Logic as an axiom of science. I mean sort of obvious, logic is an axiom of math and logic itself. 

You glossed over it but a critical axiom in science is the assumption that probability is real. This is huge because it is completely arbitrary. Probability is just an arbitrary mathematical game where we can do certain calculations and come up with certain meaningless values called "probabilities" but the fact that these probabilities happen apply to real world events is just assumed.

Answer (score 1):

cf. [Hilbert's 6<sup>th</sup> problem: "Can physics be axiomized?"](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/hilbert/problems.html#prob6) of his  [Mathematics Problems](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/hilbert/toc.html) lecture delivered before the International Congress of Mathematicians at Paris in 1900:

> 6. Mathematical treatment of the axioms of physics
>
> The investigations on the foundations of geometry suggest the problem: *To treat in the same manner, by means of axioms, those physical sciences in which mathematics plays an important part; in the first rank are the theory of probabilities and mechanics.*
>
> As to the axioms of the theory of probabilities,<sup>14</sup> it seems to me desirable that their logical investigation should be accompanied by a rigorous and satisfactory development of the method of mean values in mathematical physics, and in particular in the kinetic theory of gases.
>
> Important investigations by physicists on the foundations of mechanics are at hand; I refer to the writings of Mach,<sup>15</sup> Hertz,<sup>16</sup> Boltzmann<sup>17</sup> and Volkmann.<sup>18</sup> It is therefore very desirable that the discussion of the foundations of mechanics be taken up by mathematicians also. Thus Boltzmann's work on the principles of mechanics suggests the problem of developing mathematically the limiting processes, there merely indicated, which lead from the atomistic view to the laws of motion of continua. Conversely one might try to derive the laws of the motion of rigid bodies by a limiting process from a system of axioms depending upon the idea of continuously varying conditions of a material filling all space continuously, these conditions being defined by parameters. For the question as to the equivalence of different systems of axioms is always of great theoretical interest.
>
> If geometry is to serve as a model for the treatment of physical axioms, we shall try first by a small number of axioms to include as large a class as possible of physical phenomena, and then by adjoining new axioms to arrive gradually at the more special theories. At the same time Lie's a principle of subdivision can perhaps be derived from profound theory of infinite transformation groups. The mathematician will have also to take account not only of those theories coming near to reality, but also, as in geometry, of all logically possible theories. He must be always alert to obtain a complete survey of all conclusions derivable from the system of axioms assumed.
>
> Further, the mathematician has the duty to test exactly in each instance whether the new axioms are compatible with the previous ones. The physicist, as his theories develop, often finds himself forced by the results of his experiments to make new hypotheses, while he depends, with respect to the compatibility of the new hypotheses with the old axioms, solely upon these experiments or upon a certain physical intuition, a practice which in the rigorously logical building up of a theory is not admissible. The desired proof of the compatibility of all assumptions seems to me also of importance, because the effort to obtain such proof always forces us most effectually to an exact formulation of the axioms.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>14. Cf. G. Bohlmann, "Ueber Versicherungsmathematik," from the collection: F. Klein and E. Riecke, *Ueber angewandte Mathematik und Physik*, Teubner, Leipzig, 1900.</sup>
> <sup>15. E. Mach: *Die Mechanik in ihrer Entwickelnng*, Brockhaus, Leipzig, 4th edition, 1901.</sup>
> <sup>16. H. Hertz: *Die Prinzipien der Mechanik*, Leipzig, 1894.</sup>
> <sup>17. L. Boltzmann: *Vorlesungen über die Principe der Mechanik*, Leipzig, 1897.</sup>
> <sup>18. P. Volkmann: *Einführung in das Studium der theoretischen Physik*, Teubner, Leipzig, 1900.</sup>

Comment: Given Hilbert's program didn't even suceed for maths, how can it be said to be valid for physics? The same Incompleteness Theorem that sank it surely applies also to physics.

Comment: @CriglCragl Yes, see: "[A Late Awakening to Gödel in Physics](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~aversa/misc/A%20Late%20Awakening%20to%20G%C3%B6del%20in%20Physics.pdf)"

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:

1. There is no such thing as the scientific method.
2. Axioms exist within theories and are called postulates.  However, they don't typically translate across theories.
3. Ochman's Razor is not an axiom or postulate, but rather a guideline for pick what theory to believe when you have two or more competing theories that explain the data equally well.

Comment: (Ockham's razor is a heuristic.)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're presupposing that the axiomatic method in mathematics is the essence of mathematics and given its success in coming up with irrefutable truths one should search for ways of axiomatising other sciences; but this presupposition may not hold; here's Poincares take on this in his book *Science & Hypothesis*:

> What is the nature of mathematical reasoning? Is it deductive as commonly thought? Careful analysis shows us it is nothing of the kind; that it participates to some extent in the nature of inductive reasoning and for that reason is fruitful.

In other words mathematics is more akin to a science and it's a false economy to turn sciences into axiomatic mathematics.

Comment: You're talking in terms of formalization of axioms. These things can be talked about informally. In order for someone to BELIEVE science in real they must assume certain aspects of reality are real. These are the axioms of a science. Nobody just believes science is real because it's science... science is taking advantage of some aspect of reality that everyone assumes to be true and that's why people trust science. For example science assumes Logic is real, and science also assumes Probability is real. These are two axioms that science is built upon.

Answer (score 0):

As @Geremia pointed out, finding axioms for the mathematical portion of physics has certainly been *proposed*, and undoubtedly attempts have been made.  However: Even if such axioms could be found, sufficient to cover all known phenomenae, and amenable as a basis for the mathematical portion of physics, there would still be the entirely separate issue of *checking whether the world conforms to those axioms*, and that is something no axioms can address.

Also, as @Jenhawk777 points out, the very validity of *doing* physics requires a lot of assumptions, which could be called 'axioms' - but I think that doesn't quite address the question asked (yes?).

Answer (score 0):

To deconstruct and construct outcomes we need an approach that is systematic. Even if it is a random sample that we observe we need a systematic approach to evaluate it. The validity or the correctness of the scientific method and the axiomatic approach is a non-starter, this is because they are set to to constantly evolve. You can set the axioms and try to describe the outcome and if it doesn't then we keep on changing the axioms. If our hypothesis is wrong we keep on changing it in the scientific method. What we need is clarity, I.e. the limitations of our axioms and hypothesis. If you step outside of the frame "science" and label it as information(knowledge or outcomes) the purpose of scientific method and the axiomatic approach will be clear. To add to this, seperation of information into fields of study is also another deconstruction for simplicity and to evaluate information based whether if it belongs to the feild of mathematics or physics is s bad approach, for information is boundless...